# How to duplicate Storyboards to all screen sizes without auto-layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard

I have Storyboard that is made for devices with 4inch Display.
I want to duplicate the Storyboard to make one for each size + iPad. Unfortunately the auto-layout is disabled and it is complex Design.
I read that i can edit the storyboard as text and change

```
key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"
```

And in appDelegate

```
int height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
 if (height == 568) {
   storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 }
```

And then I can scale the views manually for each view [which I have more than 40].

1)Isn't there a faster way? Easy way? Time efficient way?
2)Is this way is correct and actually works?

Thanks.

Comment: Autolayout is the only smarter way. It reduces your efffort by 90% . My suggestion is to don't struggle in creating multiple storyboards for different screen sizes. Have one storyboard which should adapt itself to all screen sizes.

Comment: @Mr.T May i know the way?

Comment: use freeform storyboard, and aply the constraints to all elements. You will get conflicting constraints in the beginning, but that is fine, start with one simple view and constraint its leading edges to the screen.